# PHP Change and save value of a variable without DB

Tags: php, database, variables, fwrite

I have a little programm for a forum that looks into a thread and saves the date of each users' last post into a MySQL database. So far, so good, no problem with that. But if I want to change the thread the program looks into, I of course have to open the php-file and change the threadid-number manually. Here's a code-snippet of how it's like now:

```
// change this variable if you want to use another thread
$thread = 452;  

// save last post of each user into db
$result = $db->query("SELECT userid, MAX(posttime) AS maxpost 
                FROM bb$n_posts WHERE threadid = '$thread'
                GROUP BY userid ORDER BY userid");
```

I want to share my programm with users that have no clue about php, so I want to make it more user-friendly and use a GUI for that. I would implement a select-box with all available threads, the user chooses one and via submitting the id will be set. Again this would be absolutely easy if I would just use MySQL for that, but that would be kind of a waste. I would have to create a new table with just this one variable in my database and I would like to avoid that.

Is there a way to change the variable directly in the file and save it? Like, get this variable from this file, replace value with this and save file. I tried thinking about using fwrite and the like for it, I just don't know how to get one specific variable from a file.

Comment: You could store the data in the file as JSON and then parse the JSON when you get it from the file.

Comment: Why do you need to have that $thread variable persistent anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Make a file, e.g. `id.php` and put there only

```
<?php
$thread = 452;
```

and include this file to your main php file.

Then write a function that will update the file via `file_put_contents()`

Comment: This will cause chaos when multiple people are choosing threads. You might end up getting a thread which someone else chose.

Comment: He asked exactly this: "Is there a way to change the variable directly in the file and save it?"

Comment: I agree, I'm just saying it would be a terrible way of solving the problem.

Comment: In this case that wouldn't be the problem. It's always only one specific thread you want to choose and it has to be displayed for every user. A thread can only be chosen by a moderator. It would work this way. :)

Comment: And if you have two moderators?

Comment: So if it works for you, I would be very grateful, if you accept this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making it more complicated than it needs to be, you can simple have a form, with the dropdown list, that submits to itself and read the $_POST.

Something like this, in your 'GUI':

```
<form action="page_name.php" method="POST">
  <select name="thread_id">
    <option value="1">Thread Name 1</option>
    <option value="2">Thread Name 2</option>
    <option value="3">Thread Name 3</option>
    <option value="4">Thread Name 4</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Then in you PHP, do:

```
// change this variable if you want to use another thread
$thread = $_POST['thread_id'];  

// save last post of each user into db
$result = $db->query("SELECT userid, MAX(posttime) AS maxpost 
            FROM bb$n_posts WHERE threadid = '$thread'
            GROUP BY userid ORDER BY userid");
```

This will allow multiple users to use the page.

Edit: Full example

```
<form action="tester.php" method="POST">
  <select name="thread_id">
    <option value="1">Thread Name 1</option>
    <option value="2">Thread Name 2</option>
    <option value="3">Thread Name 3</option>
    <option value="4">Thread Name 4</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST))
{
    // change this variable if you want to use another thread
    $thread = $_POST['thread_id'];  
    echo $thread;
    exit;
}
?>
```

As [hynner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2503810/hynner) pointer out, watch out for that SQL injection vulnerability. Read more on bindParam, etc [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338)

Comment: You might want to get rid of that sql injection vulnerability :-)

Comment: IF is_numeric / is_int $_POST['thread_id'] would go a long way to closing that potential

Comment: But this way it doesn't memorize which thread was chosen for the next time. The option to change the thread is on an interface where you can also edit other options and I don't want to chose the thread anew every time I want to change something else.

Comment: Then I'd say store the thread id in the user's session, and retrieve it from the session when he gets to the page to select the thread. That will make it 'remember' the setting as well as solve any multi-user issues.